# RabbitMQ with Spring redelivering message forever

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using Spring with RabbitMQ and I'm trying to avoid the message redelivery in case of a runtime exception occurs. I've tried to set the `requeue-reject` to `false` in `listener-container` and configure a custom error handler that throws an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`. It seems that both of strategies failed and the message continue redelivery forever. Any ideas of the reason?

Thank's for help.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit" xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.1.xsd">

    <rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitMQConnectionFactory" host="localhost" port="5672" username="guest" password="guest" />

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitMQConnectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="rabbitMQConnectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:queue name="q1" />
    <rabbit:queue name="q2" />

    <rabbit:listener-container error-handler="errorHandler" connection-factory="rabbitMQConnectionFactory" concurrency="10" transaction-manager="transactionManager" requeue-rejected="false">
        <rabbit:listener ref="q1Listener" method="consumeMessage" queue-names="q1" />
        <rabbit:listener ref="q2Listener" method="consumeMessage" queue-names="q2" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>

    <bean id="errorHandler" class="ErrorHandler" />

    <bean id="q1Listener" class="Q1MessageConsumerBean" />
    <bean id="q2Listener" class="Q2MessageConsumerBean" />
</beans>
```

Comment: You need to "Nack" the message in order to remove it from the queue and mark it as a failure.

Comment: Hi, can you give an example code of errorHandler bean ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `requeue-rejected="false"` and `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` does the same in case of `RuntimeException` from the target listener.

Here is a test-case which shows that `requeue-rejected="false"` works well.

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    exchange="foo" routing-key="foo" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="foo" />

<rabbit:direct-exchange name="foo">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="foo" key="foo" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>

<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" auto-startup="false" requeue-rejected="false">
    <rabbit:listener ref="listener" queue-names="foo" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="listener" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="spy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.RejectedTests$ThrowListener" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

---

```
@Autowired
private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

@Autowired
private SimpleMessageListenerContainer container;

@Autowired
private ThrowListener throwListener;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("foo");
    container.start();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    Mockito.verify(throwListener).onMessage(Mockito.any(Message.class));
}

public static class ThrowListener implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        throw new RuntimeException("intentional reject");
    }

}
```

The `Mockito.verify(throwListener).onMessage(Mockito.any(Message.class));` confirms that the `onMessage` is called only once for the first delivery. The second delivery isn't happened, because our message is rejected and dropped from the RabbitMQ Broker.

I see only the signle place, where it isn't happened independently of `requeue-rejected="false"` - `RabbitResourceHolder#rollbackAll()`:

```
for (Long deliveryTag : deliveryTags.get(channel)) {
    try {
        channel.basicReject(deliveryTag, true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new AmqpIOException(ex);
    }
}
```

However this block is reached, only on the TX commit and an Expception on that commit. So, we cause a TX rollback in that case:

```
private boolean doReceiveAndExecute(BlockingQueueConsumer consumer) throws Throwable {

    Channel channel = consumer.getChannel();

    for (int i = 0; i < txSize; i++) {

        logger.trace("Waiting for message from consumer.");
        Message message = consumer.nextMessage(receiveTimeout);
        if (message == null) {
            break;
        }
        try {
            executeListener(channel, message);
        }
        catch (ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException e) {
            break;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            consumer.rollbackOnExceptionIfNecessary(ex);
            throw ex;
        }

    }

    return consumer.commitIfNecessary(isChannelLocallyTransacted(channel));
```

Pay attention to the last line. `consumer.rollbackOnExceptionIfNecessary(ex);` is a case when an exception is thrown from the listener. Otherwise we reach that last line and wait for the external TX commit.

Let us know if that is your case.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much for your answer. I made some other testes and now I have the expected behaviour with the same configuration (removed errorHandle).

FYK, in one of my tests I've detected an scenario that redelivery occurs and it may be something related to what you said:

Flow: `Listener` -> `Facade` -> `Service`. All transactional.

If `Service` throws a `RuntimeException` and I caught in `Facade` and don't rethrow (swallow the exception), the message is redelivered. Looks like the tx is rollbacked even I swallow the exception and the message is redelivered - ignoring the `requeue-rejected` property.

Thank you again.

Comment: So, can we get a hook of the transaction rollback so that message can be rejected without requeue ?